# Is it possible to connect more than the two standard streams to a terminal in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, bash, shell, command-line

Consider the following simple program, and suppose it is in a file called `Test.c`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    fprintf(stdout, "Hello stdout\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "Hello stderr\n");
}
```

Suppose I compile this program into an executable called `Test` and run it as follows.

```
./Test > Out 2> Err
```

After this run, I will have two files `Out` and `Err`, which will contain the two messages respectively.

This is wonderful because I can have two different types of messages normally printed to the console, and then filter one or both by using bash redirection. However, the fact that I can only do this kind of filtering with two file descriptors seems very limiting.

**Is there some way to open a third or nth file descriptor which *points at the terminal output*, so I could filter it separately?**

The syntax might be something like this.

```
./Test > Out 2> Err 3> Err2
```

I speculate that `bash` may have some rudimentary support for this because of the following test, which seems to imply that `bash` will treat the number after a `&` as a file descriptor.

```
$ ./Test >&2
Hello stdout
Hello stderr
$ ./Test >&3
bash: 3: Bad file descriptor
```

Comment: Your "speculation" is quite right. But unless the program knows what to do with the open fd number x, that's just a wasted open handle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At a shell, running either

```
exec 3>/dev/tty
```

...or...

```
exec 3>&1
```

...will open file descriptor 3, pointing it to your TTY explicitly (in the first case), or to the location at which stdout is currently writing to (in the second).

---

If you want to use this in a program, I would strongly suggest taking an FD number to write extra logs to as an optional argument:

```
yourprogram --extra-logs-fd=3
```

...combining that output with stderr, or suppressing it entirely (as appropriate) if no such option is given. (A user who wanted extra logging to go to stdout could thus use `--extra-logs-fd=1`, or `--extra-logs-fd=2` for stderr).

Even better, if your only target OS is Linux, is just to accept a filename to write to:

```
# to write to a file
yourprogram --extra-logs=extra_logs.txt

# to write to FD 3
yourprogram --extra-logs=/dev/fd/3

# to write to a tee program, then to stderr (in ksh or bash)
yourprogram --extra-logs=>(tee extra_logs.txt >&2)
```

...of course, you *can* do all that with the FD mode (just redirect `3>extra_logs.txt` in your shell in the first case, and `3> >(tee extra_logs.txt >&2)` in the third), but this makes you do the work of managing FD numbers by hand, and with what advantage?

Comment: For ease of programming and security, just open any expected file-descriptor not given to `/dev/null`.

Comment: You will probably want to wrap this file descriptor in a FILE* stream with `fdopen`

Comment: While I agree with your suggestion for ease of use, I'm still interested in whether I can perform this addition of a file descriptor directly in my program, so the user does not have to perform a shell command beforehand. Also, for completeness, how would you close such an extra stream, short of starting a new shell?

Comment: You can open `/dev/tty` in your program, but that doesn't do your user any good, since doing that prevents them from being able to redirect that stream from their shell. For the shell to be able to control what the stream is attached to, the shell needs to be passing the stream into the program under it.

Comment: @merlin2011, ...keep in mind that all redirections -- `3>some.log` and the like -- happen *before* the program being run is started. Thus, the program can't do anything to change the semantics of the redirections -- they've already been done before it's launched!

Comment: @merlin2011, ...though one thing you _can_ do in your program is check whether any FD 3 is defined at all, and if not, open it to `/dev/null` or copy stderr to it or somesuch. That's not a good/safe practice, though, because who knows if a script or something else in the environment is already using that FD number for its own purposes? You could badly mess up the execution of a script that's calling you if you hijack its FDs.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, Thanks for all the clarifications.