# Is it possible to redirect stdout to a non-stderr stream inside a shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, file-descriptor, io-redirection

This is related but orthogonal to my [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28909347/is-it-possible-to-connect-more-than-the-two-standard-streams-to-a-terminal-in-li).

Consider the following shell script, which I'll put in a file called Play.sh.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Send me to standard out"
echo "Send me to standard err" >&2
```

When I run this, I can redirect stdout and stderr.

```
$ ./Play.sh  > /dev/null
Send me to standard err
$ ./Play.sh  2> /dev/null
Send me to standard out
```

All this works as desired.

---

I would like to open a third stream and force `echo` to output to the third stream, so I can filter to it. Something like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Send me to standard out"
echo "Send me to standard err" >&2
echo "Send me to stream 3" >&3
```

Unfortunately, the third stream does not attach to `/dev/tty` by default.

**Observed Output**

```
# This works as desired
./Play.sh  3> /dev/null
Send me to standard out
Send me to standard err

# This does not work as desired.
$ ./Play.sh
Send me to standard out
Send me to standard err
./Play.sh: line 5: 3: Bad file descriptor
```

**Desired Output**

```
# This works as desired
./Play.sh  3> /dev/null
Send me to standard out
Send me to standard err

# I would like stream 3 to go to /dev/tty ONLY when not redirected.
$ ./Play.sh
Send me to standard out
Send me to standard err
Send me to stream 3
```

**Is there an incantation I can use inside the shell script to make the third stream point at /dev/tty if and only if the parent process does not redirect it?**

Effectively, I'd like the third stream to behave exactly the same way as `stdout` and `stderr`: Default to `/dev/tty` and allow the parent to redirect.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work as desired"? Your script overrides the caller's assignment of file descriptor 3, so it now redirects to `/dev/tty` instead of `/dev/null`. If you desire something else, what exactly do you desire, and why doesn't your code then do that instead?

Comment: I did a bit more research and I think I need to edit my question.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/206786/testing-if-a-file-descriptor-is-valid shows how to check if a file descriptor exists, if that is what you are actually trying to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For completeness, based on tripleee's comment, what I actually wanted was the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Send me to standard out"
echo "Send me to standard err" >&2


if ! (printf '' 1>&3) 2>&-; then
  # File descriptor 3 is not open
  # Option 1: Redirect fd3 to stdout.
  exec 3>&1
  # Option 2: Redirect fd3 to /dev/null.
  # exec 3>/dev/null
fi

# No error here.
echo "Send me to stream 3" >&3
```

With this modification, a parent process can redirect 3 when it desires to do so, and otherwise have it as part of stdout.

```
$ ./Play.sh
Send me to standard out
Send me to standard err
Send me to stream 3

$ ./Play.sh 3> /dev/null
Send me to standard out
Send me to standard err
```